# boolean not working properly

Tags: modifiers

I have 1 Sphere and 1 Cylinder. I try to join them by boolean. when I Join the cylinder with Sphere, Cylinder behaves weird while sculpting however Sphere seems to be normal. There seems to be some issue of either Clean mesh or Normals. But not  sure how to fix that in Blender 2.8. Please help[image]

Comment: Is it necessary to use the boolean? eg To model cylinder with sphere attached could add a uv sphere, choose a latitude edge ring, delete all verts "south" and extrude.

Comment: Or create and position one with Ctrl+R and then do what batFINGER says. And Ctrl+J is always there.

Comment: This looks like Z-fighting. Do you still have the cylinder, as well as the sphere-plus-cylinder, so they're overlapping?

Answer (score 2):

Just to illustrate batFINGER's point:

Delete faces with *Delete > Faces*.
Select an edge loop and extrude downwards.

[image]

To close the bottom, just *Fill* and *Poke faces*.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You should adjust the Overlap Threshold of Boolean Modifier.

In my case correct Overlap Threshold is from 0.000001 to 0.001:
[image: Overlap Threshold of Boolean Modifier]

After apply Boolean Modifier sculpt is correct:
[image: Sculpted]